How can I make nested geometry nodes instances?
I'm relatively new to Blender so sorry for my inexperience, but I was doing a simple project to try and learn how Geometry Nodes works. for this I've chosen to make a simple forest mainly using Geometry Nodes. What I've been trying to do is have a plane that generates a cluster of pebbles at random and then add that to my floor.


Each instance of the object has the same geometry, and to create a more realistic/random look for the floor. I want the first object to make a new seed for the pebbles in a different way each time a new instance is placed. Is this possible and how so?

instead of plugging one object in the instance of instance on points, try using a collection info node in it and there you can move your different pebbles in there.

You probably meant to say "parented" instead of "nested"? some translators do that.
